# transforming variables

Tags: volatility, data, regression, wavelet

I am would like to create a  regression model with different variables however before using these variables in my regression model I would like to transform the variable in order to make it more stationary .The variable that I would like to transform has time varying volatility . So far I have used  different scaling techniques to transform my variable but I have not gotten  the most desired results .

This is what my variable looks like plotted

[image]

As one can see the variable has time varying volatility , what techniques can I use to better transform my variables specifically variables with time varying volatility

Comment: Do you mean apart from a GARCH model?

Comment: @kurtosis apart from GARCH  yes

Comment: Have you thought about breaking it up into two processes, one for the 5 sample mean and a 5 sample standard deviation

Comment: @JakeFreeman how would you do such a thing can you elaborate on that